# Python regular expression to replace unencoded ampersands in text

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with an upstream system that sometimes sends me text destined for HTML/XML output with ampersands that are unencoded:

```
str1 = "Stay at this B&B"
str2 = "He&#8217;s going to Texas A&M"
str3 = "He&#8217;s going to a B&amp;B and then Texas A&M"
```

I need to replace the unencoded ampersands with `&amp;` while preserving the ones that are part of character references or are already encoded.

(Fixing the upstream system isn't an option, and since the text sometimes arrives partially encoded, re-encoding the whole string isn't something I can do, either. I'd really just like to fix this nagging issue and get on with my life)

This regular expression is catching it fine, but I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax to do a `re.sub`:

```
re.findall("&[^#|amp]", str3)
```

I'm not sure how to properly substitute the text; I have a feeling it's going to involve `re.group` but that's a weakness in my regular expression-foo.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What if it sends `&nbsp;`? Or are `&amp;` the only encoded characters that don't involve the `&#\d{4};` syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using a negative lookahead for this.  It will cause the match to fail if the `&` is followed by `#xxxx;` (where x is a digit) or `amp;`, so it will only match standalone `&` characters and replace them with `&amp;`.

```
re.sub(r"&(?!#\d{4};|amp;)", "&amp;", your_string)
```

Comment: `re.sub(r"&(?!amp;)", "&amp;", r'He&#8217;s going to Texas A&M')` gives `'He&amp;#8217;s going to Texas A&amp;M'`, which is not "ok"

Comment: @Tadeck - Thanks, somehow missed that in the question, edited to fix.

Comment: Misses hex encoded and most Latin 1 entities, e.g. `&quot;`, `&#xA7`, etc.

Answer (score 12):

If the ampersand is part of a character entity, it can be any named entity (not just `&amp;`), a decimal entity, OR a hexadecimal entity.  This should cover it:

```
re.sub(r'&(?![A-Za-z]+[0-9]*;|#[0-9]+;|#x[0-9a-fA-F]+;)',
       r'&amp;', your_string)
```

Comment: Yup, this is the one you want. +1

Answer (score 0):

First guy was close:

```
re.sub(r"&(?!#\d{4};|amp;)", "&amp", your_string)
```

Comment: My edit from 20 minutes ago is this exact answer (except with the correct replacement).